# AWS Elasticsearch IAM as master user getting AuthorizationException trying to put data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

[Screenshot of ES Role Selection console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dGEP.png)

Trying to put a document to AWS ES cluster. Code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import boto3

host = 'search-dev-operations-2-XXXXXXXX.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com' # For example, my-test-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
region = 'us-east-2' # e.g. us-west-1

service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

document = {
    "title": "Moneyball",
    "director": "Bennett Miller",
    "year": "2011"
}


es.index(index="dev-operations-2", doc_type="_doc", id="5", body=document)

print(es.get(index="dev-operations-2", doc_type="_doc", id="5"))
```

Getting this error message:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthorizationException: AuthorizationException(403, '{"Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/andrey.tantsuyev@XXXtechnology.com is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPut with an explicit deny"}')
```

Set up `arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:user/andrey.tantsuyev@XXXtechnology.com` as a IAM master user through Fine-grained access. This is my AWS user

Anybody could help me please? Have no ideas why I"m not authorized.

[Screenshot of ES Cluster details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh2R5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem in ElasticSearch, this is being blocked based on the policies associated to your IAM user.

Go to the IAM service console and look up the permissions for the `andrey.tantsuyev@XXXtechnology.com` user.  It appears that there is a "Deny" statement associated with one of the groups/policies attached to the user that matches the `es:ESHttpPut` action.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that andrey.tantsuyev@XXXtechnology.com had MFA restrictions. Ones I've implemented assumeRole with MFA credentials everything started working fine.